# Dojo request.post to Rails Fails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, dojo

I'm converting a website from Symfony to Ruby on Rails and am finally down to my javascript pop up email contact form. I don't want to rewrite the form or the java script as it took a lot of work to get it to work in the first place. That will be phase two.

Here's where I'm having the problem:

```
    sendBtn = new Button({
    label: "Send",
    onClick: function(){
        if (emForm.validate() == true){
            // Post the data to the server
            request.post("/contact/create",
                {data: domForm.toObject("contact-form"),
                // Wait 2 seconds for a response
                timeout: 2000

            }).then(function(response){
            emailDialog.hide();
            alertDialog.set("content",response)
            alertDialog.show();
            });
        }
    }
},"submit-btn");
```

I know it gets to the request.post as I copied the line "email.Dialog.hide()" just before it and it hid it. I later added code to catch any errors. It goes there immediately and not after the two second timeout. I'm using dojo here, by the way. So I suspect it doesn't like the "/contact/create" as it's the only thing I changed.

In my routes.rb I have:

```
  get 'contact/create'
```

Do I have the right information in my post? If not how do I get there? The javascript is included in application.html.erb so it can be invoke from all pages on the site.

In case it's pertinent, my contact_controller.rb is currently just this:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html {}
      #format.js   {}
      format.json { render :json => {:response => 'Amazing, it works'} }
    end
  end
  def show
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I had the right path in the request.post statement. I found out my copying the Javascript into my html.erb file so I could use

```
<%= contact_create_path %>
```

in it's place. I ended up getting the same value so that wasn't the problem. I then checked my Firebug console. Rails sends a nice dump of the problem. I was getting a 404 error. The problem was that I was doing a post and there was no route for it. So I changed the routes.rb file from

```
get 'contact/create'
```

to

```
post 'contact/create'
```

This might cause me other problems later on if I want to do a non-Javascript version.

I then got another error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in ContactController#create
```

Through the help of Stackoverflow I found the fix. I added the second line below:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
...
```

Again, this solution may cause other problems. Skipping verification doesn't seem like a good thing. I had a number of other problems getting the whole process to work, but their specific to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your network tab in dev tools, it should tell you why it is failing post... I'd say try adding `handleAs: 'json'` option to your request.post. For more on dojo/request, read [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/request.html)

Comment: Thanks. I used the Firebug log instead. The post was being sent as json.